# IPv6 source address selection with addrlabel and netplan

Tags: networking, netplan, nfs, ipv6

I have configured my Ubuntu 22.04 via netplan like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.10.10/24
        - 2001:db8:6789::10/64
      gateway4: 192.168.10.1
      gateway6: 2001:db8:6789::1
      nameservers:
          search: [example.com]
          addresses: ['2001:db8:6789::5', 192.168.10.5]
```

This works, and my client gets a static IPv6 and a dynamic IPv6. The latter is preferred as source per default, which is nice regarding privacy when using services on the Internet.

However, when using my services on my LAN, especially NFS, I want to use the client's static IPv6. I can get it to work by using these two commands:

```
ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:db8:6789::5/128 label 99     # NFS server
ip addrlabel add prefix 2001:db8:6789::10/128 label 99    # NFS client
```

But how can I make this permanent so this `addrlabel` is set at boot before the `nfs-mounts` start (also at boot)?

Answer (score 0):

netplan 0.100 and later support `label` for this as documented at https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types.  Ubuntu 22.04 includes netplan 0.105, so this is supported.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

Firstly, Netplan is *not* an alternative to (systemd-)networkd or NetworkManager. Netplan is a "network configuration abstraction renderer", and for the example above, netplan actually creates a systemd-networkd file based on the netplan-configuration. It is saved as `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp3s0.network`, and the content is:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.10.10/24
Address=2001:db8:6789::10/64
Gateway=192.168.10.1
Gateway=2001:db8:6789::1
DNS=192.168.10.5
DNS=2001:db8:6789::5
Domains=example.com
```

So, to add `ip addrlabel` to my config, I had to create my own systemd-networkd-networkfile. It also needed to be (in lexical order) before the autogenerated file from netplan.

My solution was to create `/etc/systemd/network/01-enp3s0.network` with the following content:

```
[Match]
Name=enp3s0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.10.10/24
Address=2001:db8:6789::10/64
Gateway=192.168.10.1
Gateway=2001:db8:6789::1
DNS=192.168.10.5
DNS=2001:db8:6789::5
Domains=example.com

[IPv6AddressLabel]
Label=99
Prefix=2001:db8:6789::5/128

[IPv6AddressLabel]
Label=99
Prefix=2001:db8:6789::10/128
```